# How to switch AP quickly in iOS

Tags: ios, wifi

I have written an app to collect AP data in our teaching buildings.

```
NSMutableArray *wifiList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
CFDictionaryRef captiveNetWork = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));
NSDictionary *myDictionnary = (__bridge NSDictionary *)captiveNetWork;
NSString *bssid = [myDictionnary objectForKey:@"BSSID"];
```

But I find out that my phone didn't switch to the nearest AP quickly, especially when two AP are close to each other.
So I need to reopen my App or re-open the wifi connection, which is indeed inefficient.
What's more, there is not public api in iOS to control the wifi connection.

Is there any method?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control WiFi access point connection from an iOS app.  In order to achieve best possible WiFi roaming, it needs to be controlled from the access point.  Enterprise grade WiFi solutions have a central management system that provides seamless hand-off between APs.